# SQL conversion script causes System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, exception, memory

When I run the script below, I get this exception.  It crashed after about 20 minutes (+/- a couple minutes).  How can I prevent this exception without creating batches?  I want to do this for all client records that need it.

Exception:

```
An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

SQL conversion script:

```
SELECT clientid 
INTO #Temp 
FROM client

DECLARE 
    @iteratorId INT, 
    @phone NVARCHAR(64), 
    @fax NVARCHAR(64),  
    @contactid INT

WHILE (SELECT Count(*) FROM #Temp) > 0 
BEGIN 

    SELECT TOP 1 @iteratorId = clientid FROM #Temp 
    SET @contactid = NULL

    --try and grab the first non null phone number in priority order
    SET @phone = ISNULL((
        SELECT TOP 1 
            dayphone
        FROM contact c 
        INNER JOIN dbo.clientcontact cc ON c.contactid = cc.contactid
        WHERE 
            clientid = @iteratorId
            AND cc.contacttypeid=2
            AND c.dayphone IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY cc.parentclientcontactid, priority DESC
    ),'')

    --try and grab the first non null fax priority order
    SET @fax = ISNULL((
        SELECT TOP 1 
            fax 
        FROM contact c 
        INNER JOIN dbo.clientcontact cc ON c.contactid = cc.contactid
        WHERE 
            clientid = @iteratorId
            AND cc.contacttypeid=2
            AND c.fax IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY cc.parentclientcontactid, priority DESC
    ),'')

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM clientcontact WHERE clientid=@iteratorId AND contacttypeid=3 AND priority=1)
    BEGIN       
        INSERT INTO dbo.contact
                ( versionnumber ,
                  createdate ,
                  firstname ,
                  lastname ,
                  title ,
                  middleinitial ,
                  dayphone ,
                  nightphone ,
                  mobilephone ,
                  fax ,
                  securefax ,
                  extranetusername ,
                  extranetpassword ,
                  email ,
                  active ,
                  testfaxpagereceived ,
                  ftpoptionid ,
                  testresultnotify
                )
        VALUES  ( 0 , -- versionnumber - int
                  GETDATE() , -- createdate - datetime
                  NULL , -- firstname - nvarchar(64)
                  NULL , -- lastname - nvarchar(64)
                  NULL , -- title - nvarchar(64)
                  NULL , -- middleinitial - nvarchar(64)
                  NULL , -- dayphone - nvarchar(64)
                  NULL , -- nightphone - nvarchar(64)
                  NULL , -- mobilephone - nvarchar(64)
                  NULL , -- fax - nvarchar(64)
                  '' , -- securefax - bit
                  NULL , -- extranetusername - nvarchar(64)
                  NULL , -- extranetpassword - nvarchar(64)
                  NULL , -- email - nvarchar(127)
                  0 , -- active - bit
                  0 , -- testfaxpagereceived - bit
                  NULL , -- ftpoptionid - int
                  NULL  -- testresultnotify - bit
                )
        SET @contactid = @@IDENTITY

        EXEC dbo.procContactSave 
            @contactid = @contactid, -- int
            @firstname = "General", -- nvarchar(64)
            @middleinitial = NULL, -- nvarchar(64)
            @nightphone = NULL, -- nvarchar(64)
            @lastname = "Info", -- nvarchar(64)
            @email = NULL, -- nvarchar(127)
            @fax = @fax, -- nvarchar(64)
            @testfaxpagereceived = 0, -- bit
            @mobilephone = NULL, -- nvarchar(64)
            @securefax = 0, -- bit
            @active = 1, -- bit
            @extranetpassword = NULL, -- nvarchar(64)
            @extranetusername = NULL, -- nvarchar(64)
            @title = NULL, -- nvarchar(64)
            @ftpoptionid = NULL, -- int
            @dayphone = @phone, -- nvarchar(64)
            @testresultnotify = 0, -- bit
            @audituserid = 0 -- int

        EXEC dbo.procClientContactSave 
            @clientcontactid = NULL, -- int
            @priority = 1, -- int
            @clientid = @iteratorId, -- int
            @contacttypeid = 3, -- int
            @contactid = @contactid, -- int
            @audituserid = 0 -- int
    END 

    DELETE #Temp Where clientid = @iteratorId -- delete row so we don't loop over it again 
END
DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Comment: What do `dbo.procContactSave` and `dbo.procClientContactSave` do - are they using some CLR functionality?

Comment: just stored procedures .. that do INSERT commands mainly

Comment: Those stored procedures both output 1 result set in the SQL window.  Would that cause the SSMS to run out of memory you think?  It seems odd for SQL-Server-2008 to run out of memory.  I would think it can handle 11,000 records in a single script.

Comment: An `OutOfMemoryException` cannot be catched and handled in a normal .NET application, thereby SMSS would completely crash which is not the case as far as I understand you. Therefore I do not suspect SMSS of crashing, but rather that some CLR assembly code is being executed somewhere in your SPs which uses up more memory than SQL Server is permitting for the CLR code.

Comment: It first displayed that error, but it didn't crash SSMS immediately.  Only when I tried running another query a few minutes later, it then crashed.  I'm willing to bet money it was the amount of data it was displaying.. the window scroll bar in the results was miniature.

Comment: what is CLR?  I only know about .NET CLR (common language runtime).  Is that what you were referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 2 stored procedures mentioned in my comments, I was calling standard web application stored procedures, which inserted a record, but also returned that record in a result set (with just the 1 record) for each iteration in the script.  The script ran for 1.5 minutes when I commented the SELECT statement in those 2 stored procedures, so I imagine it was crashing from the amount of data SSMS was displaying from those result sets.  That prevented the memory crash, not to mention the reduction in time it took to run (from 20+ min to 1.5 min).